# invalid expire time in SETEX, sPort: 12702 in Redis

Tags: c#-4.0, redis

I am getting error while using **Redis cache time=0**. Same time using with Redis cache time=1, it is working as expected.

How to set Redis cache time value is 0. Please help

**ErrorMessage**

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"invalid expire time in SETEX, sPort: 12702, LastCommand: ","ExceptionType":"ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException"

I want set 0 as expire time, why because i am using dynamic page and it has many chunk. The Redis cache time coming from config file. Example: Chunk 1 with redis cache time of 2 minute. In particular time i dont want redis cache, that time i go and change 0 as redis cache time in configuration file.

Comment: why do you want to set `0` as expire time? Do you want to delete that key?

Comment: I want set 0 as expire time, why because i am using dynamic page and it has many chunk. The Redis cache time coming from config file. Example: Chunk 1 with redis cache time of 2 minute. In particular time i dont want redis cache, that time i go and change 0 as redis cache time in configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In particular time i dont want redis cache, that time i go and change 0 as redis cache time in configuration file.

It seems that you don't want to store a key by commanding redis to store a key. Which is very inconvenient.

If you don't want to change your application code than you could save it just for 1 sec, which is minimal. As `setex` command expect the time is **positive** means **greater than zero**.

Otherwise, you can tweak your code by ignoring to store in cache while ttl is zero. Or you can save it for **1 milisecond** in redis using [**psetex**](https://redis.io/commands/psetex) insted of **setex**.

Comment: I am using fraction value that is 0.5 minute, now i am getting proper flow of execution as expected. Thanks